# How do I get the pom.xml path using gradle?

Tags: gradle

Let's say I have the following `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

configurations { libs }

dependencies {
  libs 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.5.Final'
}

task showPomPath {
  doLast {
    configurations.libs.???.each { pomFile ->
      println pomFile.path
    }
  }
}
```

Practically I don't know what to put instead of the `???` here: `configurations.libs.???.each`.

I looked through the documentation and couldn't find anything helpful in the DSL for `Configuration`. The closest I got to something is:

```
configurations.libs.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts
```

But it's not what I want... Could you give me some hints where I should look?

Comment: I don't think there is a supported way to get it, and I think it's even stored as an ivy.xml in the cache. What do you need it for?

Comment: I need to republish some artifacts to a new server, but in a different layout (from `ivy.xml` to `pom.xml` (the question is about `pom.xml` to make it more understandable and simpler). The solution I thought of is: 1. get hold of `ivy.xml`, 2. convert it to `pom.xml`, 3. publish it to new server

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser: I don't mind if I can use some of Gradle's internal classes: this is just a throw away script - run once, test if everything is working as expected and throw it away...

Comment: I guess I could bypass gradle and use ivy directly to download and convert the `ivy.xml` file to `pom.xml`... Is there a better option? I know that for a while gradle used ivy for dependency resolution... so that should be a good alternative, right?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to do the digging yourself. Perhaps you could reconstruct the pom/ivy.xml url from the module information (obtained via `configuration.incoming` or `configuration.resolvedConfiguration`) and download it directly.